# move data from a listview having tree view into another listview wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, desktop-application

I am new to `XAML` and `WPF`. I'm given a task to move data from one `ListView` having `TreeView` to another simple `ListView`. I can move `ListView` to `ListView` but not sure about how to do this if we use `TreeView` in one of the `ListView`. I'm selecting any value then pressing the right move `Button` with double greater sign text to move it to the right `ListView` and then back to the `TreeView` on the right if selected and pressed the `Button` with double less then sign text.

[image: This the image to show you the whole concept about what i want.]

```
public partial class TreeView : Window
{
    public PermissionModel PModel;
    string currentItemText;
    int currentItemIndex;
    public TreeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<ScreenModel> ScreenPermissions = GetScreenPermissions();
        this.DataContext = ScreenPermissions;
        PermissionView.ItemsSource = ScreenPermissions;
    }

   public List<ScreenModel> GetScreenPermissions()
    {
        ScreenModel accountScreenPermission = new ScreenModel()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Account",
            Permissions = new List<PermissionModel>()
            {
                new PermissionModel()
                {
                    Id=1,
                    Name="Add Account"
                },
                new PermissionModel()
                {
                    Id=2,
                    Name="Edit Account"
                }
            }
        };

       ScreenModel saleScreenPermission = new ScreenModel()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Sale",
            Permissions = new List<PermissionModel>()
            {
                new PermissionModel()
                {
                    Id=1,
                    Name="Add Sale"
                },
                new PermissionModel()
                {
                    Id=2,
                    Name="Edit Sale"
                }
            }
        };
        return new List<ScreenModel>()
        {
            saleScreenPermission,accountScreenPermission
        };
    }

   private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        currentItemText = PermissionView.SelectedValue.ToString();
        currentItemIndex = LeftListBox.SelectedIndex;

       RightListBox.Items.Add(currentItemText);
        if (PModel != null)
        {
            PModel.Name.ToString();
        }
        ApplyDataBinding();
    }
    private void ApplyDataBinding()
    {
        PermissionView.ItemsSource = null;
        PermissionView.ItemsSource = PModel.Name;
    }

   private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

   }
```

}

> This is databind code

```
<ListBox Name="LeftListBox" Width="230" Height="250">
            <TreeView Name="PermissionView">
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Permissions}">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: You already used the `data-binding` tag. That is the answer. You don't move data from one listview or treeview to the other because the listviews don't have data. They *bind* to the data. If you want something to disappear from one view and appear in another, remove it from the first view's source and add it to the other's. If the source is eg a List<T>, all you have to do is add the selected item to the second list and remove it from the first

Comment: yes @PanagiotisKanavos i know 'data-binding' is the solution to it as i mention that i did it in for listview to listview. but here the problem came up using treeview. But now not sure how to remove and add and back add to the treeview.

Comment: 1. get the data 2. move from source 3. add to destination

Comment: @Bashirahmad I'm not sure you understand what data binding is or does yet. The views have no data. The data remains in the original lists, arrays, whatever. If you want to change what appears in a view, change the *list or array* and the view will update itself. If you want more help, you'll have to post your code - the XAML that shows how you bind and the viewmodel/code-behind code that contains the data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i am posting the code. please check that out

Comment: You forgot the ScreenModel and PermissionModel classes. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.